# flash component for printing graph

Tags: flash, charts, graph, graph-theory

Is there a class/component/library for drawing graphs in flash ? 
And i am not talking about the bar charts, but actual graph like neural graphs, or road graphs etc.
Also if someone has experience with it, how big a graph can be plotted out until it becames to big and it loads verry hard ( how much nodes, routes ).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://flare.prefuse.org/

Flare is pretty freakin sweet and can handle lots of data.

Comment: Does this handle graph-theory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) graphs (the kind the OP wants)?

Comment: it has some really great node/edge graphing capabilities. Check out the samples. http://flare.prefuse.org/demo